# R: GBM prediction results all similar

Tags: r, gbm

In the course of using GBM to predict a response for my test data, I've noticed that the GBM predicted response has a very low variance despite my test's response varying a lot. Furthermore, I've noticed that the GBM's response tends to be hover around mean of the actual response.

I'm sure this isn't a problem with my predictors as XGB and RandomForest implementations are able to pick up this variance. However, I would still prefer using GBM due to its rel.inf feature.

Anybody has any experience in this? Or know if I have to somehow scale the results of the GBM before using it?

Comment: I have the same problem.  Here a simple example to reproduce: 
library(gbm)
fit <- gbm.fit(
  y = c(rep(1, 100), rep(-1, 100)),
  x = data.frame(a = c(rep("A", 100), rep("B", 100))),
  distribution = "laplace"
)
predict(fit, n.trees = 100)